# Why is my ethernet port not working correctly?

Tags: drivers, ethernet, computer-building

I recently built a computer using the components listed below.  I have installed and verified Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. I inserted the motherboard driver disk and installed all the drivers.

My problem is that the Ethernet port does not seem to be working.  I plug the cord into the port, but the indicator lights on the port do not turn on, and Windows does not recognize that a cord is plugged in.

This is my first foray into computer building, so please don't spare the any answers on account of them being too obvious.  Is there a specific cable that I failed to plug into the motherboard? I was thinking that the port may need to be separately powered from the power source, but I couldn't find any cords or ports that seemed to be missing.

Here is my component list:

- [Case](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811119233)
- [Power Supply](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817171038)
- [Motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128521)
- [CPU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103962)
- [Memory](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231278)
- [SSD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820227393)
- [HDD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148767)
- [Graphics Card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125363)
- [DVD Burner](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16827106289)

Comment: If the network port light doesn't turn on, first thing to do is check the cable & the other "end" of the connection: keep that cable connected to the network switch (or wall port) and connect another computer to it.

Comment: @Caspar I have plugged the other end into my laptop and it works fine there.  That is what led me to think that the ethernet port might need to be powered separately somehow, but the USB ports on the back panel work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: Try another ethernet cable

2: Does the ethernet adapter show in device manager?

2a: If it does, are there any errors or does it report it is working correctly?

3: If it does not show in device manager, check to be sure it is not Disabled in the bios.

4: It is possible you got a bad ethernet controller, rma the motherboard back to Newegg to exchange for another new board.

Comment: The adapter does show in the device manager, and it does not show any errors, just that there is no cable attached.  I will have to check the BIOS, but it should be enabled if it shows up in the device manager, right?  is it worth disassembling the entire machine to send the motherboard back, or should i just spend the $15 for an ethernet card?

Comment: Did you try another cable or 2? Correct it would not show up in DM if it is disabled in the bios. If the nic is bad on the motherboard I would rma the board, no telling what else is wrong that you may not detect for a few months.

Comment: Man... you got like a PCI adapter hanging around?  That is what I would try :)